# Change UIView Layer - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I try to implement UIView with sequence. With below code the output like in this picture. (This is normal behaviour)

[image]

But I want to line up like below picture

[image]

**Elements sorted from right!**

```
imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: participantView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: CGFloat(-(counter * widthX - 5 * counter)) ).isActive = true
```

**What can I do now?**

```
   let widthX = 30
   var counter = 0
   for x in element {

          guard let image = x.image else { continue }
          let urlX = URL(string: "...")
          let imageView = UIImageView()
          participantView.addSubview(imageView)

          imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
          imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: participantView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: CGFloat(-(counter * widthX - 5 * counter)) ).isActive = true
          imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: participantView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
          imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: participantView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
          imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
          imageView.backgroundColor = .white

          imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 15
          imageView.clipsToBounds = true
          imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
          imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1
          imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
          counter += 1

          imageView.kf.setImage(with: urlX)
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
participantView.addSubview(imageView)
```

with

```
participantView.insertSubview(imageView,at:0)
```

position of 1 ,2 ..etc (left/right alignment) depends on image

Comment: I applied this " participantView.insertSubview(imageView, at: counter) ". But it has no sense. 0 is frontest view ?

Comment: 0 is the back most view

Comment: "var viewX = 100 , participantView.insertSubview(imageView, at: viewX) , viewX -= 1 ".  Problem is continue .

Comment: no make it 0 for all , don't automate it with a var ,  it's a replacement as in answer

Comment: I dont make 0 for all

Comment: do it and the last one will be inserted back - most and so on

Comment: Thanks Khan. I m very appreciate .0 is correct answer . If the title is not correct , you can change .